# Getting zero when calculating percentage of two buttons pressed

Tags: swift, math

I've two buttons one is light side button and other is called dark side button. When any of the button is pressed do this:

```
    lightSideInt = lightSideInt! + 1
    totalClicks = totalClicks!+1

    let lightPercent = (lightSideInt!/totalClicks!) * 100
    let darkPercent = (darkSideInt!/totalClicks!) * 100

    darkSideButton.setTitle("\(darkPercent)%",for: .normal)
    lightSideButton.setTitle("\(lightPercent)%",for: .normal)
```

And same for the dark button except for the `darkSideInt = darkSideInt! + 1` everything is same. `darkSideInt`, `lightSideInt` & `totalClicks` are global variables.

Now what happens is that when I press the button for the first time it give one button title `100%` and the other `0%` and after that use has to dismiss the screen and then come on this screen again. So this time as the variables are global they already have the value so when I press the button I can see the increment is happening successfully but the button title is `0%` and no matter how many times I press the button it remains the same.

These are the global variables:

```
var darkSideInt: Int?
var lightSideInt: Int?
var totalClicks: Int?
```

Comment: Looks like integer math. Show your data types. And why all of the "crash me" operators (`!`) ?

Comment: ignore the `!` operators for now I've updated the question kindly see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applying the `/` operator to two `Int`s, the result will be of type `Int` as well, hence your issue. You need to convert both variables to `Double` before applying the division.

```
let lightPercent = Int(Double(lightSideInt)/Double(totalClicks) * 100)
let darkPercent = Int(Double(darkSideInt)/Double(totalClicks) * 100)

darkSideButton.setTitle("\(darkPercent)%",for: .normal)
lightSideButton.setTitle("\(lightPercent)%",for: .normal)
```

It doesn't make sense to define `lightSideInt` and `darkSideInt` as optionals if you are going to force unwrap the value assigned to them. Just define them as non-Optionals and then you can get rid of the force unwraps in the percentage calculations.